# Poor Birt Chart Font Resolution

Tags: charts, fonts, birt

I'm using Birt 4.5.2 to render some charts for a few reports.  When I run the reports locally on my Mac, the fonts in the charts look very nice and render exactly as I expect -- Axes scales, bar chart data points, labels, etc. -- all clear and crisp resolution.  However, when I run the report on an AWS Linux instance, all fonts in the generated chart image render extremely poorly.  All have the look of a dot-matrix printer -- stair-steppy, no character smoothing.

The generated chart is an SVG and I'm using fonts that are installed on the Linux instance, and I've tried a few different things -- `reportContext.getAppContext().put("CHART_RESOLUTION", 300 );` e.g. -- nothing seems to help.

Switching fonts in the chart does not seem to help -- the font changes slightly, but the resolution is still equally bad.

Does anybody know a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Really simple fix after all -- the Report Design ImageDPI property needs to be set to 300.  Select the `.rptdesign` file in the Outline panel.  Select the Properties window panel - if it isn't already open, navigate to Window->Show View->Properties.

In the list of properties is an ImageDPI property.  Double-click the value and set to 300.

Or, if you want to just edit the raw XML, choose that and search for the `<ImageDPI>` tag and modify it right there.

Lastly, just make sure that all the fonts you're using in your chart are installed on the AWS instance.